# Open button's image on Android when button is visible

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have a large canvas where I placed multiple buttons. Each button has an image which is opened based on the button click event. I want to change it such a way so that when a button enters to the screen area, it will automatically open the button image.

I guess I need to find the current button view (that is visible on the screen) and then use functions to simulate the button click event (`View.performClick();`). As I am not entirely sure, any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to take both view button view and image at the same position, when click on button view then this view hide and show image.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to add ImageButton and change the image/background by click

Something like that:

```
boolean isShown;    
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(isShown){
            //set empty bg
        }else{
            //set right content
        }
        isShown = !isShown;
    }});
```